¿Cuál es el error lógico en la función de operación booleana en Ensamblador GAS Windows 10 de arquitectura x86_64 con compilar TDM-GCC 10.3.0?
Problema
Estoy haciendo como mini proyecto educativo, una biblioteca o librería (no sé que es) de el tipo de dato booleano en C, usando Ensamblador para definir las funciones.
El problema que tengo es que el valor retornado siempre es 1 o 0 dependiendo de la función.
En la función bool_or siempre retorna 1 incluso si los parámetros son 0.
La función bool_and también siempre devuelve 1 independientemente de los parámetros.
El mismo comportamiento aplica a mi última función bool_or.
La verdad no estoy seguro de la convención, pero intento hacer las funciones con la convención cdlec.
El código está documentado con el comportamiento esperado, puede que tenga algún error la forma en la que explico en la documentación.
bool_and:
        push rbp           # Guardar el valor original del registro rbp
        mov rbp, rsp       # Movemos el valor del registro rsp a rbp
        sub rsp, 24        # Establecemos el marco de la pila 24
        mov rax, [rbp+16]  # Pasamos el primer argumento [rbp+16] al registro rax
        and rax, [rbp+24]  # Operación AND con el segundo argumento [rbp+24]
        test rax, [rbp+24] # Verificamos si rax es 0
        setne al           # Si rax no es 0, al = 1 (true); si rax es 0, al = 0 (false)
        movzx rax, al      # Extender al a rax para devolver 0 o 1
        add rsp, 24        # Reestablecemos la pila
        pop rbp            # Le devolvemos el valor a rbp
        ret                # Retornamos y devolvemos el control a la función donde se ejecuta

    bool_or:
        push rbp           # Guardar el valor original del registro rbp
        mov rbp, rsp       # Movemos el valor del registro rsp a rbp
        sub rsp, 24        # Establecemos el marco de la pila 24
        mov rax, [rbp+16]  # Pasamos el primer argumento [rbp+16] al registro rax
        or rax, [rbp+24]   # Operación OR con el segundo argumento [rbp+24]
        test rax, rax      # Verificamos si rax es 0
        setne al           # Si rax no es 0, al = 1 (true); si rax es 0, al = 0 (false)
        movzx rax, al      # Extender al a rax para devolver 0 o 1
        add rsp, 24        # Reestablecemos la pila
        pop rbp            # Le devolvemos el valor a rbp
        ret                # Retornamos y devolvemos el control a la función donde se ejecuta

    bool_not:
        push rbp           # Guardar el valor original del registro rbp
        mov rbp, rsp       # Movemos el valor del registro rsp a rbp
        sub rsp, 16        # Establecemos el marco de la pila 16
        mov rax, [rbp+16]  # Pasamos el argumento [rbp+16] al registro rax
        test rax, rax      # Verificamos si rax es 0
        sete al            # Si rax es 0, al = 1 (true); si rax no es 0, al = 0 (false)
        movzx rax, al      # Extender al a rax para devolver 0 o 1
        add rsp, 16        # Reestablecemos la pila
        pop rbp            # Le devolvemos el valor a rbp
        ret                # Retornamos y devolvemos el control a la función donde se ejecuta

Espero que el comportamiento de las funciones sea el siguiente
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pexbool.h"

int main() {
    bool a = true;
    bool b = false;

    printf("bool_and(%d, %d) = %d\n", a, b, bool_and(a, b)); // Debería imprimir 0
    printf("bool_or(%d, %d) = %d\n", a, b, bool_or(a, b));   // Debería imprimir 1
    printf("bool_not(%d) = %d\n", a, bool_not(a));           // Debería imprimir 0
    printf("bool_not(%d) = %d\n", b, bool_not(b));           // Debería imprimir 1
    
    return 0;
}

El resultado al compilar y ejecutar el código es el siguiente
bool_and(1, 0) = 1
bool_or(1, 0) = 1
bool_not(1) = 0
bool_not(0) = 0

Depuración
Depurador
WinDbg
Información de Pila
 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 0000005d`623ffc28 00007fff`b79eef98     ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0x14
01 0000005d`623ffc30 00007fff`b59ce3eb     ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0xb8
02 0000005d`623ffc60 00007fff`b751a155     KERNEL32!ExitProcessImplementation+0xb
03 0000005d`623ffc90 00007fff`b751a7c5     msvcrt!_crtExitProcess+0x15
04 0000005d`623ffcc0 00007ff7`9ab414b5     msvcrt!doexit+0x171
05 0000005d`623ffd30 00007ff7`9ab414f6     main!__tmainCRTStartup+0x325 [C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v8-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c @ 336] 
06 0000005d`623ffe00 00007fff`b59c7374     main!mainCRTStartup+0x16 [C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v8-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c @ 214] 
07 0000005d`623ffe30 00007fff`b79dcc91     KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
08 0000005d`623ffe60 00000000`00000000     ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21

Información de los registros
RAX: 0000000000000000   RBX: 0000000000000000   RCX: 00007FFFB79DD110   
RDX: 000001A379375910   RSI: 0000000000000000   RDI: 0000000000000000   
RIP: 00007FFFB79DCC70   RSP: 000000270C3FFD28   RBP: 0000000000000000   
R8:  0000000000000000   R9:  0000000000000000   R10: 0000000000000000   
R11: 0000000000000000   R12: 0000000000000000   R13: 0000000000000000   
R14: 0000000000000000   R15: 0000000000000000   
EFLAGS: 00000200 CF=0 PF=0 AF=0 ZF=0 SF=0 TF=0 IF=1 DF=0 OF=0
LastErrorValue: 0x00000000
LastStatusValue: 0x00000000

Datos extra

Tengo instalado GAS con TDM-GCC y lo uso con el compilador.

Las funciones intentan ser cdlec, pero en cierto punto se distorsiono y ya no estoy seguro de la convención.

No conozco al 100% las convenciones cdlec y stdcall, solo la fastcall la conozco bien.



Deberías mencionar qué compilador y qué convención estás utilizando para tus funciones en ensamblador. Es fastcall? Estás seguro que el parámetro se encuentra en rbp+16 y no rbp+28 o rbp+32?

Ya hice algunos cambios @Mateo

Mí duda sobre la ubicación de los parámetros es porque restas 24 más los 8 bytes del push. Con lo cuál la información debería estar en rbp+32 y rbp+48. Depurar el programa y examinar la memoria te darán una pista. Tanto gdb como wingdb permiten ver los registros y la memoria

Eso no lo sabía tendré que depurar para ver @Mateo

Respecto a eso, para qué necesitas espacio en el stack? No estás guardando nada en el marco de la llamada actual. Te puedes ahorrar la suma y la resta.

Debido a las convención cdlec, sino me equivoco, los parámetros se pasan a través de la pila @Mateo

Hasta ahorita puede hacer la depuración @Mateo

Voy a actualizar la pregunta @Mateo

Puede que el problema sea que no se está llamando la función usando cdecl. Lee el chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154173/discussion-between-asmazreg-and-mateo

Lo acabo de leer, pero el problema persiste @Mateo

Además, eso que mencionas sobre la compatibilidad aplica más a Linux que a Windows. Según tengo entendido. @Mateo

Volví a actualizar la información de depuración. @Mateo

Tal como dices, la pila no recibe los valores. Use fastcall y funciona perfectamente. Voy a investigar y si tengo un avance lo publico. @Mateo

He investigado y al parecer es imposible usar convenciones de llamada diferentes a fatcall, tal como dices. Da una respuesta para poder marcarla como correcta. Gracias por la ayuda @Mateo

Aunque usemos los atributos correspondientes, el compilador nos advierte que son ignorados.
<source>:3:53: warning: 'cdecl' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
    3 | bool bool_and(bool a, bool b) __attribute__ ((cdecl));
      |                                                     ^
<source>:5:52: warning: 'cdecl' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
    5 | bool bool_or(bool a, bool b) __attribute__ ((cdecl));
      |                                                    ^
<source>:7:45: warning: 'cdecl' attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
    7 | bool bool_not(bool a) __attribute__ ((cdecl));
      |       

De hecho, si vemos el desensamblado notamos que intenta pasar los parámetros mediante registros en lugar del stack. Claramente está utilizando la convención de x86-64 System V ABI.
# Inicializa las variables en el stack
mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-1], 1
mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-2], 0
# Carga las variables en los registros esi y edi
movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rbp-2]
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rbp-1]
mov     esi, edx
mov     edi, eax
call    bool_and(bool, bool)

Como dice esta respuesta, parece ser que tales atributos no pueden usarse en 64 bits. De hecho, si compilamos el código para 32 bits (con la flag -m32) veremos que el desensamblado es el siguiente:
# Inicializa las variables en el stack
mov     BYTE PTR [ebp-9], 1
mov     BYTE PTR [ebp-10], 0
movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [ebp-10]
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [ebp-9]
# Se cargan los parámetros al stack
sub     esp, 8
push    edx
push    eax
call    bool_and(bool, bool)
# Se limpia el stack como dicta la convención cdecl
add     esp, 16

